# Is it legal to paraphrase questions taken form test prep books/service to a new audience in another country for a different exam? Do fair use apply?

Tags: exams, intellectual-property

Is it legal to paraphrase questions taken form test prep books/service to a new audience in another country for a different exam? Do fair use apply?

**About my business**

**It is not the same exam**

**Not the same country**

**No copy/Paste only paraphrasing.**

**It is for profit.**

**What is legal here and what isn't legal ? If it is not how to make it so**

I've been noticing that Grockit doing the same thing without any issue.
For example the GMAT questions that I have seen on Grockit's platform are a close copy of the actual official GMAT questions, not all of them but a good number. I have attached an image of a question from Grockit and the original GMAT question which is from the Official Guide to GMAT 2015(Question#228).

Grockit is test prep company.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not "fair use" if it is for-profit.

Comment: So how does Grockit did it if it not legal? thanks

Comment: @paulgarrett, is that your legal interpretation, or do you have a SCOTUS decision on point? There are possible fair use uses that could also be for profit. A long quote in a for-profit magazine which is used for the purpose of criticism/review of the original could easily be ruled a fair use.

Comment: @BillBarth, I'm thinking first of the easiest argument for "fair use", namely, suitable teaching and other academic uses. Even the not-within-university-walls examples of "fair use" appear (in my I'm-not-a-lawyer perception) to be parallel to the academic justifications. After all, people get paid at universities, just as critics get paid, but the "quoting" is not the primary product in either case, and the use does not "take away trade" from the original producer. Using a product in a fashion that reduces the market for the original strikes me as outside the intent... But I don't know...

Comment: @BillBarth so what do you think about my case. thanks

Comment: @AhmedAli, Sorry, but I'm not going to give you legal advice here. I'm not a lawyer!

Comment: Incidentally, you should not use the word "construct" because "construct" has a very specific technical meaning in geometry, and using "construct" as done above will likely introduce what is called irrelevant variance. Note how the original wording carefully avoids this issue. However, the original wording still seems a bit problematic to me. I would omit "can be drawn", as this can mean different things to different people and thus "can be drawn" can also introduce irrelevant variance. *Right triangle ABC is positioned* [located?] *in the xy-plane so that* . . .